# Remove column using class name in jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to remove column using class name in jQuery DataTables?

My code is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/ebRXw/801/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "responsive": true,
         "aoColumnDefs": [
             { 

                 "className": 'never', 
                 "targets": 1
             }
             ]
    } );
} );
```

But the first column is not deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use class name assigned to `th` element in table header (`col-hide` in my example) in [`targets`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) option (without the leading dot `.`) to target certain columns and [`visible`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.visible) option to make these columns hidden.

```
"columnDefs": [
    { targets: "col-hide", visible: false }   
]
```

For example:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "responsive": true,
    "columnDefs": [
        { targets: "col-hide", visible: false }   
    ]
} );
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/804/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: @mosestoh, glad to help. If you just wanted to hide second column, you could have used  `columnDefs: [{ targets: 1, visible: false }]` instead without assigning classes.

Comment: Okey Grycode.com. Thank you. You much help me. I'm still a beginner. I still need a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:none;` with added class to hide the targeted column as

```
.never {
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/803/